# Python Pandas idiom for converting TimeSeries with lists as values into a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, pandas

Suppose I have the example TimeSeries below:

```
ts = pandas.TimeSeries({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':[6,7,8,9,10]})
```

The best method that I could think of for converting this to a 5-column DataFrame is as follows:

```
tsDataFrame = pandas.DataFrame(
                               [tuple(elem) for elem in ts.values], 
                               index=ts.index.values
                              )
```

Is this the best-practices idiom for making this happen, or is there any sort of constructor or built-in that sort of "flattens" a column whose values are arrays into a set of columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
In [3]: pandas.DataFrame(list(ts.values), index=ts.index)
Out[3]: 
   0  1  2  3   4
a  1  2  3  4   5
b  6  7  8  9  10
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Brevity is a big plus here.